# Sort main query by subquery

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I need to list all the conversations of a user, sorting by the last received message (same as the conversations of whatsApp).

In this way it orders correctly, but duplicates the conversations.

I tried to use `distinct()` to solve this, but it ended up asking to put the `messages.created_at` inside the `select`, then it duplicates the results again.

```
Chat::where('chats.from_id', $user_id)
        ->join('messages', 'chats.id', '=', 'messages.chat_id')
        ->select('chats.*')
        ->orderBy('messages.created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: I think you need to show us some sample data from both tables.  It is not obvious what you mean by "duplicate" here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```php
Chat::where('chats.from_id', $user_id)
    ->join('messages', 'chats.id', '=', 'messages.chat_id')
    ->select('chats.*', DB::raw('max(messages.created_at) latest_message'))
    ->groupBy('chats.id')
    ->orderBy('latest_message', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

You can also use relationships, e.g.:

```php
Chat::where('chats.from_id', $user_id)
    ->withCount(['messages as latest_message' => function($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('max(created_at)'));
    }])
    ->orderByDesc('latest_message')
    ->get();
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using `SELECT chats.*` which is a valid query when the database supports functional dependency, even in MySQL's `strict` mode.

Comment: Sorry bro...didn't see that, right you are +1.  I have seen some pretty atrocious Laravel queries, so I jumped the gun and assumed you weren't paying attention :-)